# Can't find Jetty's GzipHandler class when running JUnit against SnappyData

Tags: apache-spark, junit4, snappydata

SnappyData v.0-5

My goal is to run a snappydata driver program to connect up to SnappyData in a remote server.  I wrote a Junit to do this.  However, when I run it, I get an error with the SparkContext is instantiated:

```
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/GzipHandler**
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$4.apply(JettyUtils.scala:235)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$4.apply(JettyUtils.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.startJettyServer(JettyUtils.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.bind(WebUI.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:499)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$13.apply(SparkContext.scala:499)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:499)
```

My pom.xml dependencies are:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.snappydata</groupId>
        <artifactId>snappy-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.snappydata</groupId>
        <artifactId>snappy-cluster_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
 <dependency>


@Test
public void testInsertDataFromCsv() throws Exception {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setMaster("spark://snappy-lead-host:8090");
    conf.setAppName("MySparkApp");

    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    SnappyContext snappyContext = new SnappyContext(sc);

    String fileResource = "data.csv";

    DataFrame dataFrame = snappyContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true").load(fileResource);

    JavaRDD<Row> row = dataFrame.javaRDD();
    System.out.println(row.toDebugString());

    dataFrame.write().insertInto("example_table_col");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A primary feature of SnappyData cluster is long-running Spark executors (which are same as the data store JVMs themselves). The intention of the program seems to be to connect to the existing cluster, but it will instead attempt to launch a new set of executor JVMs for processing which is how Spark normally works. The SnappyData lead does not support that mode since it is designed to reuse existing data nodes for execution.

This limitation in Spark is due to the fact that there can be only one driver in the cluster which is already running in SnappyData lead node, and thus no new drivers can be created (we do intend to remove this limitation in a future release). So a URL like `"spark://..."` pointing to lead node will not work. Running Spark jobs requires one of these possible deployment strategies (apart from direct SQL submission using JDBC/ODBC clients).

NOTE: for the embedded mode both `snappy-cluster` and `snappy-core` dependencies are required, while for other two modes only `snappy-core` should be added as a dependency.

**Embedded mode execution:** Like for the JDBC/ODBC clients, here execution happens in the data nodes themselves. This requires submitting the jobs via the job-server which is running on the active lead node. Program has to implement `SnappySQLJob/JavaSnappySQLJob` and submit it using REST API (either the provided `snappy-job.sh` script or something like [this](https://github.com/bluebreezecf/SparkJobServerClient) for self-contained tests). Details here: http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/jobs/

```java
public Object runJavaJob(SnappyContext snappyContext, Config config) {
    String fileResource = "data.csv";

    DataFrame dataFrame = snappyContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true").load(fileResource);

    dataFrame.write().insertInto("example_table_col");

    // for debugging
    JavaRDD<Row> row = dataFrame.javaRDD();
    return row.toDebugString();
    // return Boolean.TRUE;
}

public JSparkJobValidation isValidJob(SnappyContext snappyContext,
                                      Config config) {
    return new JSparkJobValid();
}
```

**Local split mode:** In this mode the execution cluster is a spark `local` master and thus separate from the snappydata cluster. This will not give good performance because it has to fetch lots of data from the data nodes for most queries, but it should be easiest to use for functional testing with small amounts of data. Use master as `local` and set `snappydata.store.locators` property to point to the locator (see http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/connectingToCluster/ and the link before)

```java
@Test
public void testInsertDataFromCsv() throws Exception {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setMaster("local[*]");
    conf.setAppName("MySparkApp");
    // below property can also be fetched with
    // io.snappydata.Property.Locators().apply()
    conf.set("snappydata.store.locators", "snappy-locator-host:10334");

    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    SnappyContext snappyContext = new SnappyContext(sc);

    String fileResource = "data.csv";

    DataFrame dataFrame = snappyContext.read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true").load(fileResource);

    JavaRDD<Row> row = dataFrame.javaRDD();
    System.out.println(row.toDebugString());

    dataFrame.write().insertInto("example_table_col");
}
```

**Split mode execution:** Lastly the execution cluster can be a normal Spark/Yarn/Mesos cluster which will talk to the snappydata cluster as a normal data store. This is how spark connectors for other products work (like Cassandra connector where Cassandra is separate from the Spark cluster). It can be run on the same nodes as the snappydata cluster for best performance and snappydata will try hard to ensure that execution is routed so that data from only local table data is fetched or inserted. Start a separate Spark cluster using `start-all.sh` from either the snappydata distribution itself or Apache Spark 1.6.x (or a Yarn/Mesos cluster as in [Apache Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/cluster-overview.html)). The code will be the same as the local split mode above with master pointing to the Spark/Yarn/Mesos master and not to snappydata lead. See links in the local split mode for more details.

Comment: I tried integrating the Spark JobServerClient from your link above.  The Jars it uploads become corrupt, so it doesn't really work.  Also, when I point to a good Jar, it runs the job, BUT I cannot figure out how to pass it Config properties in the startJob() API.  If you have experience with this link you recommended can you share how to do each?  Hopefully, you do, if you linked to it :)